# LVDS Display connected to Deserializer clarification needed

Tags: lcd, display, lvds, deserialiser

I need to use an LVDS display in my project.The pin configuration of LVDS display is given below(I can't share P/N here due to NDA).

[image]

[image]

As per my knowledge the PIN No 18 and 19 are Horizontal sync and Vertical Sync(Please correct me if I am wrong).

The deserializer used is [DS90UB928QSQX/NOPB](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ds90ub928q-q1.pdf?HQS=dis-dk-null-digikeymode-dsf-pf-null-wwe&ts=1709264097467&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fgeneral%252Fdocs%252Fsuppproductinfo.tsp%253FdistId%253D10%2526gotoUrl%253Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Flit%252Fgpn%252Fds90ub928q-q1).The deserailizer has no Horizontal Sync and vertical Sync PIN.

[image]

May I know is it mandatory that Horizonatl and vertical sync pins are required for the working of this display ?.

Can I make pin no 18 and 19 of the display as not connected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those pins are not sync pins.

The sync pins are already embedded in the LVDS data stream so it would make no sense for an LVDS display to require separate sync pins.

The pins just likely mirror the image horizontally and vertically.

Please double check from the pin description or ask the manufacturer.

Comment: Thank you. You are correct they are not HS and VS pins.